# haskell removes all occurrences of a given value from within a list of lists

Tags: haskell

I would like to remove all occurrences of a given value from within a list of lists. For example, 
input:

```
'a' ["abc", "bc", "aa"]
```

output:

```
 ["bc", "bc", ""]
```

so far:

```
remove :: Eq a => a -> [[a ]] -> [[a ]]
remove y xs = filter(\x -> x/= y) xs
```

I'm getting an error, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to map over the outer lists.

```
remove y xs = map (filter(\x -> x/= y)) xs
```

You don't actually need a lambda here, nicer:

```
remove y xs = map (filter(/=y)) xs
```

Comment: you can also drop `xs` on both sides

Comment: Or even `map . filter . (/=)`