# Concurrent Haskell: Acting upon the data within a custom data type

Tags: haskell, concurrency

So far in this program I have a custom data type, `Msg` which is a `C Char`. In the program, a separate thread is created and a separate function `userThread` listens for a keystroke and stores the char sent in an `MVar` that's acting as a simple communication channel between `main` and `userThread`

I have gotten to the point, using `deriving (Show)` where I'm able to print the Msg as to the terminal, like a string. If the user types `j` the output is:

```
C 'j'
```

(Note it also prints C when I only want the char itself)

I have an existing list and my aim is if the char is NOT in that list, then add it. If it IS, then don't add it and remove all instances of that char in the list.

For example, if a user typed `c`, then

```
[a,b] becomes [a,b,c]
```

but

```
[f,c,c,h,c] becomes [f,h]
```

My current code is below:

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Random
import Text.Printf

data Msg = C Char deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = loop
 where
 loop = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  hSetEcho stdin False

  --already existing list    
  let x = [1, 's', 'g', 4 ,5]
  chan <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO $ userThread (chan)
  r <- takeMVar (chan)

  putStrLn $ show x
  print r

-- Listens for keystrokes from the user, the passes them to the main thread
userThread :: MVar Msg -> IO ()
userThread chan = do
  c <- getChar
  putMVar chan (C c)
```

I'm confused as I'm able to perform actions like Print on my `Msg` just fine because its actual content is a char. But when I try to ad it to a list using `r:x` the compile error says:

```
* Couldn't match type `Char' with `Msg'
      Expected type: [Msg]
        Actual type: [Char]
```

How can I make my Msg fit into this list? Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: `C r <- takeMVar chan`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although I'm still having type issues. After getting Haskell to print the `Msg` as a char by itself, I try to add it to a new empty list `* Couldn't match type [] with IO
      Expected type: IO Char
        Actual type: [Char]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seams to be that your list does not contain `C Char` but rather `Char`. This may be fixed by doing `let x = [C '1',C 's',C 'g',C '4',C '5']`.

Your `userThread` puts a `C Char` into `chan`, so when you unpack it with `takeMVar (chan)` and bind it to `r`, `r` now has type `Msg`. Because in Haskell lists can only hold values of the same type, you can not prepend an `Msg` to a `[Char]`, therefor the error. Make all the elements of `x` of type `Msg` and all will be good (hopefully...). Alternatively you can implement a

`toChar :: Msg -> Char
 toChar C c = c`

and do something like `(toChar r):x` if you insist on having `Char` in your list.

for remvoing elements from x see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050988/haskell-removes-all-occurrences-of-a-given-value-from-within-a-list-of-lists). you can then write something of the sort:

```
if elem r x then newX = remove r x else newX = r:x --if x contains Msg
if elem cr x then newX = remove cr x else newX = cr:x
   where cr = toChar r --if you insist on having chars in x...
```

hope that helps.

Comment: aside: If you are unsatisfied with the way `deriving (Show)` represents your `Msg` you  can make `Msg` an instance of the `Show` type-class by providing your own implementation of show like so: `instance Show Msg where <your implementation of show>`.